# API for just list of Uber Product Names and matching IDs

Tags: ios, swift, uber-api

I was looking at the Uber API trying to get a list of Uber Products Names and ID's only.  The "Product Types" End Point required longitude and latitude, and will only return product available for that location.

I don't see this in the doc but is there a much easier way to get a list of just all the products and their ID's.  Seems silly to have to parse a data set of trips, then for each trip item make more API calls to get the Product name for that trip.

I guess my point is it would be much easier and efficient to make a single call, cache that data locally so it can be used to display the descriptive name of uber products when parsing trips/history

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this API is not available at the moment, but we'll pass this feedback to our product team.

Comment: Thx for the response.  I hope this is looked into seriously.  It makes API calls very expensive to have to do this every time to identify a Product ID.

Comment: @Lavvo `GET /v1/products` more information at [Developer Tutorial](https://developer.uber.com/docs/tutorials-rides-api)